# Iron-Router and Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk, iron-router

Iron-router seems to break the functionality of the Facebook Javascript SDK.

I want to display a popup through which a logged in user can send a private message to their friend on Facebook.

After doing

```
window.fbAsyncInit = ->
    FB.init({appId: fb_app_id, status: true, xfbml: true})
```

I call

```
FB.ui({method: 'send', app_id: fb_app_id, to: fb_object.fb_id, link: link, display: 'iframe'}, (response) ->
    ...
)
```

This works great when the route is first loaded. But if I go to another route, then come back to this one, then try to call the above FB.ui method, it fails:

```
Error
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js:1787:26)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js:449:20)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js:445:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js:445:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js:445:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js:445:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js:445:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js:445:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js:445:46)
    at window.FB.__w.signature (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all/debug.js:445:46)
```

What is causing this? How do you get around it?

Answer (score 0):

Better solution - if using Iron Router (and you probably should be), add this to your template:

```
Template.<template-name>.rendered = function() {
    try {
        FB.XFBML.parse();
    }catch(e) {}   
};
```

Note that this requires jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out. For anyone who is having this problem, here is how I solved it.

I was placing my `<div id='fb-root'></div>` element inside layout templates. This meant that every time I switched pages or executed a route, that element would be re-rendered. I believe the Facebook SDK keeps track of that element, and since the FB SDK is only initialized once, if that element is re-rendered, I guess it loses track of it and fails.

The solution is to place `<div id='fb-root'></div>` directly inside the `<body></body>` so that it doesn't get re-rendered every time a route is executed.